# Most human beings are _____________ to kindness

Tags: exam-questions

Which option fits best in the following sentence?

> Most human beings are _____________ to kindness.

1. sensible
2. susceptible
3. vulnerable
4. impressionable

Because the words 2, 3 and 4 overlaps in terms of meaning I cannot decide which one fits in the sentences.I think the word sensible has a bit different meaning. The words susceptible, vulnerable and impressionable has a connotation a sense of being gullible and naive as children or elderly people.On the other hand for me the sentence seems to say "you can get people to do what you want if you be kind to them" as sense of "Achilles's heel "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is *accessible, liable, or subject to some influence, agency*:  susceptible to colds; susceptible to flattery.

Comment: Can we say :  "Most girls are susceptible to luxurious sport cars" ,  I mean somebody can say " You can date most of girls you like if you have a luxurious sport car because girls are susceptible to guys who has a luxurious sport car"

Comment: I wouldn't say that with "objects , things ".